# File Geodatabase to map package or map document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, map-package

I have a `file geodatabase` which is output of a certain model builder. I need to make it as input of another tool that takes only map documents or map packages.

Is there any tool in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro that creates map packages or `MXD` from `geodatabse.gdb` ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. By placing an "or" in your Question, you're effectively asking two questions, and by specifying two software options, it become four (one of which is impossible). To further complicate matters, it doesn't make ***any*** sense to convert data to a map document -- in the Esri model, map documents just contain drawing rules, not the spatial data itself. Please [Edit] the question to chose software and clarify your goal.